# Can we customize the design of buttons in cards in microsoft bot framework

Tags: css, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I know that we can modify the design by making changes to botchat.css as per our requirement. Now, I want to know that can each button be of different color as shown in the image.

[image]

[button1] [button2] [button3]

All the buttons must be of different colors.

Comment: It's pretty hard to say much unless you put some related code in here, like the markup or the classes those buttons use. But if it's styled by CSS, you can almost always do what you want here.

Comment: One must have knowledge on bot framework to understand the botchat.css. The buttons which are mentioned are from hero card and so in the css file they are mentioned under class "wc-card wc-adaptive-card hero" and based on the attachment layout it might be list or carousel. For reference,botchat.css is available [here](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css) @PraveenPuglia

Comment: Why did you put 'direct-line-botframework' if your question is about rendering? And by mentioning botchat.css, we should guess that your question is for the webchat only?

Answer (score 3):

In your `custom.css` or whatever your custom CSS file name is you can address this by using CSS like this to account for the maximum amount of buttons you will produce on a card:

```
.wc-card button:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: green;
    color: #0078d7;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.wc-card button:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: red;
    color: #0078d7;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
.wc-card button:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #0078d7;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
...
```

This CSS will produce this result:
[image]

Comment: Can you reference the source code or docs for this please @JasonSowers?

Comment: This is custom CSS added on top of the webchat control, so it is not in the source code or docs for this.